# Problem upgrading Jessie To Stretch

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

After I modified the sources.list file and changed everything from where it said "Jessie" to "Stretch", I did an `apt-get update` and it didn't work. So I did an `apt-get dist-upgrade`, and it got stuck in a loop and timed out. It does seem to have upgraded though, as you can see below

```
server@server:~$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

When I try to do an `apt-get update` now, I get this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://www.ubnt.com/downloads/unifi/debian/dists/stretch/ubiquiti/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

You changed *everything* in `/etc/apt/sources.list`  to stretch. The problem is that Ubiquity offers apparently only packages for stable and oldstable, but not for stretch.

So you should change those entries back to stable and hope that mixing releases works.